# Can I sample light rays to a texture and ouput it per-frame?

Tags: rendering

I want to integrate ray tracing with my own dynamical system which will respond to incoming light.

I would need some kind of texture (or other data buffer) applied to an object to receive the data.

Each frame, using ray tracing, I want Blender to *write* to that texture, recording the amount of light which strikes it that frame.

I want to then run my own software which reads that texture (or other data buffer), does some stuff, and outputs data to images etc.

Those output images are used during rendering so they need to be reloaded before rendering the next frame.

Is this possible?